Reconciling Geocentric vs. Heliocentric views
BH
I heard that the Geocentric view of the universe is held true by Rambam and Ptolemy. I also heard someone say that the Torah holds that the Heliocentric view is true although independent of the Geocentric view, and they said that this is from the Zohar. Also, I heard — correct me if I'm wrong — that the Rebbe said that both can be reconciled through the theory of relativity and that he also held that the Sun revolves around the Earth.
So which is it really though? Is there a source in the Torah that explains this debate? Does the Torah hold that both are true also and explains the theory of relativity even before Einstein in order to reconcile the two views even before?

The Rebbe in that letter is cheating a bit. Relativity didn't show that both theories are right but rather that both theories are wrong. There is no official center point (as Rambam etc. thought there was)

There's a whole book written on the topic of the Jewish reaction to Copernicus.

@Heliocentrism did not render Geocentrism wrong, but impractical. And so did relativity.

"All models are wrong, but some are useful" - George Box. Geocentrism is a useful model in many contexts. Heliocentrism is consistent with more precise observations of reality and is useful in many contexts. The state of the art model based on relativity is consistent with yet more precise observations and is useful in yet other contexts.

Just an addition to the Rebbe's view on this: he also said that even though it's possible that the Rambam and Gemara were speaking allegorically (i.e. spiritually) and the heliocentric view is correct from a physical standpoint, there is no reason to make that assumption, because the nature of science is to be an evolving truth, while Torah is eternal truth. So the entire concept of Torah science debate is fallacy of logical comparison.

This is not really a Torah question. But if you want here's the answer. Yes the systems can be reconciled using math. In Heliocentric system the motion of planets is described by Kepler's laws, which are simple and offer reasonably close approximations. Only with development of Einstein's Theory of General Relativity scientists discovered deviations from Kepler's laws which helped correct the forecast of the motion of planet Mercury, for example.
In Geocentric system one cannot write such elegant equations like Kepler's laws. However, if one were to use Fourier series, one could describe motion of planets with some good accuracy based on past observations.  That was the nature of the approximations of ancient Greeks (Claudius Ptolemaeus) and later Medieval astronomers, who first said that each planet moves in a circle around the Earth. Then, when they saw deviations they corrected by saying that the planet actually moves in a small circle whose center is moving in a big circle around the Earth. Then they had to introduce new and new smaller circles as the astronomers were able to get better and better measurements. Such a calculation is the same as representation of a signal by frequencies.
As far as Torah goes, one can guess that Earth is not stationary in the center of Universe, due to etymology word ארץ containing רץ - run. I.e. it's something running. Alternatively, Bereshis Rabba 5:8 teachers "Why was it called eretz? It is because it hastened [ratzeta] to perform the will of its Maker". I.e. it followed instructions to either expand or stop expanding (depending on the commentary). However, one-time hastening is not a justification for its name. Perhaps, it's constantly hastening, running, as if in a free fall (around the Sun).
Certainly, it is impossible to state what the Jewish beliefs were regarding astronomy in ancient times, because the scripture is using a very simple language and historians tend to use it as a proof of simplistic beliefs. However, some facts about ancient world, such as worship of the Sun gods, development of Babylonian and Hebrew calendars, or alignment of pyramids with stars, could be reinterpreted as some bits of knowledge lost due to wars, catastrophes, destructive practices, or history falsification (eg. Greeks after the time of Alexander, Egyptians making their history very long), etc.
To see that the Sun does not rotate around the Earth, one could notice by crossing the equator: in the Northern hemisphere the Sun circles clock-wise East - South - West; in the Southern Hemisphere - it circles counter clock-wise East - North - West. Why change of direction? Ancients knew that the Earth is round because of how the stars change their angles observed at different distant points (Athens vs. Alexandria in Egypt). Also phases of the moon switch: in the northern hemisphere in the beginning of the month - , and  - in the end of the month; in the southern hemisphere - it's reversed. However, Mishna Rosh Hashanah 2.6 gives a correct formulation regardless of the hemisphere.

So much to unpack in this question:

The Torah and the whole Tana"kh don't deal with cosmology. And when they do, they side with the ancient "flat-earth-with-a-firmament-above" view. Also, "the Torah" doesn't "hold" anything, it is all up to the Rabbinic ever-changing understanding.

There's no evidence of Heliocentric thought in pre-modern Jewish tradition. The back and forth of the Jewish sages vs the Greeks in Psohim 94b clearly shows that in the earlier Talmudic times, the sages were not only unaware of Heliocentrism but of the Earth's sphericity or the Sun rotating around the Earth.

Geocentrism assumes the Earth DOES NOT rotate and it was proven wrong by Foucault's pendulum and can not be reconciled with "relativity".

The dogma of an unbroken scientific tradition from Moses to the Talmudic sages and on is uncorroborated by all existing Jewish sources. In Hilchos Kiddush Hachodesh Rambam clearly states: "we don't possess the ancient [Hebrew] knowledge but use that of the Chaldeans and the Babylonians".
Therefore, any scientific claim found in Jewish should be assumed as coming from contemporary non-Jewish authors (a phenomenon known as "one must believe in Gentiles' wisdom"). For example, the Pharisaic/Jewish calendar was adopted from the Babylonian lunisolar calendar and the Metonic cycle.

As a rule, Rabbinic Judaism focuses on the experiential/Halachic implications of Earthly phenomena rather than their essence. I.e. the physical nature of the Sun and the Moon or the cosmological system are irrelevant to all time-related Halochos.
However, if you can show, that different cosmological systems lead to different Halachic conclusions, only then it would become a Halachic question.



Yashar Koach! There are great sources to learn.

Yes, the rabbis admitted that the Greeks (Gentiles) were right on many scientific issues. In fact, Rabbi Slifkin states that Jews were the last group in Europe to accept the Heliocentric model. If ancient Jews, including the Torah and later rabbis, knew of the Heliocentric view, why were Jews the last group in Europe to accept it? Rambam admits "we don't possess the ancient [Hebrew] knowledge," because there was no such knowledge. Joshua really believed that the sun stopped. Joshua was a soldier, not an astronomer. Thus, Spinoza mocks Joshua's ignorance.

We agree that the Torah's cosmology is primitive and unscientific. What does that say for people who believe that the Torah is the word of God? What! does not the Creator of the universe know how physics works? I have no answer.

@TurkHill I have a rather simple answer - we should drop all claims of empirical knowledge altogether. I.e. "the Torah" and the Rabbis [almost] never deal with the empirical nature of things but with experiential aspects of phenomena. This poses a huge Halachic problem as many Halochos rely on facts about reality, e.g. the calendar, Kashrus, and more. The workaround is to say that God didn't pass any scientific knowledge but let the sages decide on their own. We lose truth but save Judaism.

@AlBerko It seems to me that God did give scientific knowledge, not through the Torah or through the sages, but through our senses and a deep study of science/nature. God has revealed scientific knowledge through his creation. As King David declares: “The heavens declare the glory of God; and the firmament showeth his handy-work. Day unto day uttereth speech, and night unto night showeth knowledge" (Psalm 19).

@TurkHill It's because you live in the Western Hellenized world and you read those values into the Torah. Did you see David engaging in research? Did he try to develop better military tactics against Saul?

@AlBerko Considering he won, he probably did. Not everything has to be recorded.

The Torah definitely does not hold the Heliocentric view and the Torah (and Zohar) definitely did not know anything at all about relativity before Einstein. In fact, Rabbi Slifkin writes that Orthodox Jews were the last group of people in Europe to adopt the Heliocentric view.
Think about this. If the Torah held the Heliocentric view, why does Joshua 10 say that the sun, and not the earth, stopped in its course? Spinoza mocked Joshua, or the author of his book, for his ignorance in thinking that the sun circled the earth. The earth would stand still, not the sun. Joshua was a soldier, not an astronomer. The tale shows the ignorance of Joshua, for he should have commanded the earth to have stood still. The story of the sun’s standing still upon a hill is unscientific. The sun did not stand still for Joshua and his soldiers.
Thus, in all likelihood, the Torah held the Geocentric view. Yes, the Rebbe believed that the sun revolves around the earth. This view is likewise unscientific. Besides, if the Torah knew about the Heliocentric system, the Torah would have mentioned it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Mayans never recorded anything like that. Joshua recorded that the sun stopped because that’s what he saw happen, not because Hashem told him that’s what happened. I don’t see an explicit answer to the question anywhere in your response.

@Qwertrl My apologizes. The Mayans did not appear in my original answer. It was added by an editor. I do not know why. I would like to see his source for the Mayans describing such an event, and how does he know this was the same time that Joshua commanded the sun to stand still? Why didn't other nations record it, etc?

@TurkHill and Qwertrl apologies I confused making comments and edit - I was not as familiar with this forum when I made the edit. You are correct that Mayans could not have record of such an event because they appear long after as conquerers and destroyers of the ancient Olmec civilization. The endless night was indeed recorded by Olmecs, however its timing is not clear (if we assume global flood or creation, the reserchers find a 40,000 year record, with night coming towards more recent history).  Here's some info https://saturniancosmology.org/rec.php

@TurkHill also I saw claims that the time of Exodus was symbolized by a comet flying very close to Earth.
